# How to read all gtk.TreeModelRow (in Python)

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

I have a gtkTreeView with this model structure:

> Row One
>
> ..  Child One
>
> ....Grandson On
>
> ....Grandson Two
>
> Row Two
>
> ..Child One

I need to read each one of this rows.

How can I do?

I'm a new bee in gtk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own problem above with this code:

```
def print_tree_store(store):
    rootiter = store.get_iter_first()
    print_rows(store, rootiter, "")

def print_rows(store, treeiter, indent):
    while treeiter != None:
        print indent + str(store[treeiter][:])
        if store.iter_has_child(treeiter):
            childiter = store.iter_children(treeiter)
            print_rows(store, childiter, indent + "\t")
        treeiter = store.iter_next(treeiter)
```

**Is part of this documentation**

[Tree and List Widgets](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/treeview.html)